# Spinner won't load

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create popup (modal box) in android with a spinner that contains a list of options. This spinner is within a fragment activity. I put the following code in my `onCreateDialog` method:

```
 @Override
 protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

  AlertDialog dialogDetails = null;

  switch (id) 
  {
  case DIALOG_LOGIN:
   LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
   View dialogview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);
   ((ItemListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.item_list))
   .setActivateOnItemClick(true);
   Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.planets_spinner);
   // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
  ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
   R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
  // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
  adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
  // Apply the adapter to the spinner
  spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

   break;
  }

  return dialogDetails;
 }
```

My XML layout file is as follow:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android='http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android'
android:layout_width='fill_parent'
android:layout_height='fill_parent'
android:orientation='vertical'
android:padding='10sp' >

<EditText
    android:id='@+id/txt_name'
    android:layout_width='fill_parent'
    android:layout_height='wrap_content'
    android:hint='"Username'
    android:singleLine='true' >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id='@+id/password'
    android:layout_width='match_parent'
    android:layout_height='wrap_content'
    android:ems='10'
    android:inputType='textPassword' >
</EditText>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width='match_parent'
    android:layout_height='wrap_content' >

    <Button
        android:id='@+id/btn_login'
        android:layout_width='120dp'
        android:layout_height='wrap_content'
        android:text='"Submit' />

    <Button
        android:id='@+id/btn_cancel'
        android:layout_width='120dp'
        android:layout_height='wrap_content'
        android:layout_alignParentTop='true'
        android:layout_marginLeft='10dp'
        android:layout_toRightOf='@+id/btn_login'
        android:text='"Cancel' />
</RelativeLayout>

<Spinner
android:id="@+id/planets_spinner"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

When I open the application on my android tablet, it just closes the application. When I created a custom dialog and added the code in the `onCreateDialog` method, it was fine. Then I added the spinner code and it fails. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong and how I could get a spinner to show up.

Thanks!

Comment: Change this `Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.planets_spinner);` to `Spinner spinner = (Spinner) dialogview.findViewById(R.id.planets_spinner);`. If that doesn't work then post your logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your not getting spinner reference. Try below code:-

```
case DIALOG_LOGIN:
   LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
   View dialogview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);
   ((ItemListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.item_list))
   .setActivateOnItemClick(true);
   Spinner spinner = (Spinner) dialogview.findViewById(R.id.planets_spinner);
   // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
  ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
   R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
  // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
  adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
  // Apply the adapter to the spinner
  spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

   break;
  }
```

or

```
   Spinner spinner = (Spinner) dialogview.findViewById(R.id.planets_spinner);
```

You must have to get value from reference view.

Comment: Thank you! That worked. I put a dialog in and showed the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I tried and it seems to work perfectly for what I need to do. I'm adding the spinner to a fragment:

```
protected void onCreateDialog() 
{

    final Dialog settingdialog = new Dialog(ItemListActivity.this);  

    settingdialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);  
    settingdialog.setTitle("Settings Menu");  
    settingdialog.show();  
    spinner = (Spinner)settingdialog.findViewById(R.id.planets_spinner);  

    //Populate the dropdown list
    String[] state = {"Cupcake", "Donut", "Eclair", "Froyo",
               "Gingerbread", "HoneyComb", "IceCream Sandwich", "Jellybean",
               "KitKat"};
    ArrayAdapter<String>adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ItemListActivity.this,  
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,state);  

    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);  

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() 
    {
        /**
         * Called when a new item is selected (in the Spinner)
         */
         public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
                    int pos, long id) 
         {

               value = spinner.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
               String s = value;
               if (mTwoPane) 
               {

                   settingdialog.cancel();
                   Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
                   arguments.putInt("num", 1);
                   arguments.putString("value", s);
                   ItemListFragment fragment = new ItemListFragment();
                   fragment.setArguments(arguments);
                                         getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.item_list, fragment).commit();

               } 
               else 
               {

                   Intent detailIntent = new Intent(ItemListActivity.this, ItemListFragment.class);
                   detailIntent.putExtra("num", 1);
                   detailIntent.putExtra("value", s);
                   startActivity(detailIntent);
               }

            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) 
            {
            }

    }); 
 }
```